# Converting binary/hexadecimal to MIPS instructions

Tags: mips

For the following entries, what instructions do they represent respectively?

Binary: 00000001110001011000100000100001

Hexadecimal: 144FFF9D

I'm completely lost on what I'm doing here - searching online has produced a bunch of results that make very little sense to me, but what I've gathered is I'm basically supposed to match up the numbers to their appropriate instructions/registers, but how exactly do I know what those are? Where can I find a comprehensive list? How do I know whether it's an R I or J format function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 6 bits (it is easier to work in binary) are the opcode, from which you can determine how to interpret the rest.  This site should get you started: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

**Update**: Calling the first 6 bits the opcode is (to be too kind) misleading, but it is enough to tell you how to interpret the rest of the instruction; you may need to look elsewhere (typically at the end of the instruction) for the complete determination of the opcode.

Comment: So in the first binary example - since it has 0000 00, it would be R-format, correct? And the last 6 digits (in my case 1000 01) would be the actual function/operation?

Comment: That's what the page I linked to says.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 Type of MIPS Instructions:

- R_type: Opcode must be 000000 (the first 6 bits) and with last 6 bits we can know what is the correct instruction
- I_type
- j_type

In this case, we have a R-type MIPS instruction and thus :

```
Opcode  rs      rt     rd    shamt    funct
000000  01110  00101  10001  00000   100001
 addu   $s1 ,   $t6   , $a1
```